# Resize an image for Histogram of Gradient

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-resizing

I have an image in size of 150 pixel in height and 188 pixel in width. I'm going to calculate HOG on this image. As this descriptor needs the size of detector window(image) to be 64x128, Should I resize my image to 64x128 and then use this descriptor? like this :

```
 Image<Gray, Byte> GrayFrame = new Image<Gray, Byte>(_TrainImg.Size);
 GrayFrame = GrayFrame.Resize(64, 128, INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

I concern resizing may change the original gradients orientation depending on how it is resized since we are ignoring the aspect ratio of the image?

By the way, The image is croped and I can't crop it anymore. It means this is the size of image after cropping and this is my final bounding box.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this function, but in matlab I just ran it on an image of size 797x1300 without any question. Resizing doesn't sound right to me. Are you sure the documentation isn't talking about the bin count of the histogram that it's producing? 64 and 128 seem like pretty standard histogram bin sizes for grayscale images.

Comment: yes, I looked at the documentation `hogdescriptor` in opencv and found nothing about that. and I looked at the hog article [This Paper](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) also, but it didn't mention about that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the openCV HoGDescriptor documentation is missing.

In openCV you can change the values for detection window, cell size, blockStride and block size.

```
cv::HOGDescriptor hogDesc;

hogDesc.blockSize = cv::Size(2*binSize, 2*binSize);
hogDesc.blockStride = cv::Size(binSize, binSize);
hogDesc.cellSize = cv::Size(binSize, binSize);
hogDesc.winSize = cv::Size(imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

Then extract features using

```
std::vector<float> descriptors;
std::vector<cv::Point> locations;
hogDesc.compute(img, descriptors, cv::Size(0,0), cv::Size(0,0), locations);
```

Note:

1. I guess, that the winSize has to be divisible by the blockSize and the blockSize by the cellSize.
2. The size of the features is dependent on all these variables, so ensure to use images of same size and do not change the settings to not run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks alot LSA. You mean that I don't need to change the size of my image and I can define the block size and cell size and other parameters some va;ue appropriate to the size of my image? am I right?

Comment: by the way, The training set contains many images in different sizes. what should I do? I should resize all of them? or I can perform hog on images with different parameters

Comment: Yes you could change the window Size etc. to fit your image size. But the problem is, that the descriptor size varies with all the variables (image size, cell size, etc.). So of course you could extract these differently sized features, but how to compare them?

Comment: Good point! actually I don't know. you know I have a training set with different image in different size, I want to extract their HOGs and then compare them but I don't know how :-(

Comment: What are you going to achieve? If in these images are some objects which are of similar size (in terms of pixels), then you could work with patches, which are small enough to fit in each training image (usually the object's size is chosen) and use a sliding window approach. Btw, this is the reason, why the original detection window is of size 128x64, the inventors wanted to detect people in images, which could be surrounded by a box of that size.